# Not able to set GRADLE_HOME in mac

Tags: gradle, homebrew

I have installed gradle 4.4.1 version in mac as said in gradle.org,

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-20 15:45:23 UTC
Revision:     10ed9dc355dc39f6307cc98fbd8cea314bdd381c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation 25.221-b11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64
```

But after the below command result is

```
$ brew info gradle
gradle: stable 5.6.2
Open-source build automation tool based on the Groovy and Kotlin DSL
https://www.gradle.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gradle.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.8 ✔
==> Analytics
install: 57,909 (30 days), 162,424 (90 days), 605,424 (365 days)
install_on_request: 54,738 (30 days), 153,561 (90 days), 568,111 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

I have tried to get gradle path in `/usr/` with the following command

```
find . -type d  -iname "gradle*"
```

but can see nothing.

How to set `GRADLE_HOME` in mac?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
export GRADLE_HOME="/usr/local/opt/gradle"
```

#### Detail

You can check the installation of gradle with `brew list gradle`.

`gradle` is installed somewhere like  `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.6.2`. Cause the version will change with `brew upgrade gradle`. We'd better use the symlinked place `/usr/local/opt/gradle`.